# How do I set up an OCSP responder for multiple CA certificates?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ocsp

I want to have one OCSP responder for more than one intermediate CA issuers with OpenSSL. How would I do this? All the examples I see all respond only for one issuer certificate and one OCSP signing certificate issued by that CA. How would I respond for multiple?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that openssl's built in OCSP responder is not meant for production environments, and so only supports single CAs for testing. I'm setting up OpenCA's ocspd for production.